# ¿How to avoid record from a table in pagination if this record is not present in another related table? CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, relationship

I have a doubt doing pagination in CakePHP.

Well, I will try to be concise.

I have three tables, one table is which I paginate (1st table), another table (2nd table) dependent of this one (1st table have FK to 2nd table), and the most important, 3rd table, that has FK to 1st table. So: 3rd table-> 1st table-> 2nd table. 
I do pagination of 1st table (model) from his controller, so far everything ok, the pagination list all the records from table bd and no problems.

I need also to get records from 1st table but ordering by a record from 2nd table. No problem. **The problem IS**: I WANT not to get in pagination, records from 1st table (which i paginate it) that arent present in 3rd table.

The problem is that CAKEPHP first make a query getting records from 1st table + 2nd table. After this, it get the records from 3rd table according to the records (PK) obtained from the first query, so I cant say it: not take records from 1st table that arent present in 3rd table.

¿How can I do this?

I hope I explained.

Thank you very much.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you'll want to use is a Counter Cache. Go to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html and search for 'counterCache,' and you'll find instructions.

Basically, you want to implement a "counter cache" field in model 1, that automatically keeps count of the number of linked records in model 3. Then, to exclude records from Model 1 that have no related records in Model 3, you just add a pagination condition to say that the counter cache field must be greater than 0.

UPDATE:

If you can't use CakePHP's counter cache, then you should emulate the behaviour of the counter cache using a virtual field - see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Comment: Im going to try it and I tell you. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what is CounterCache. The problem is that I think, as I have read, that CounterCache field increase or decrease when a insert/delete action is done via CakePHP, true? So, it would be a bit "unstable" or unreal, dont u think so? If i do an operation in the database, from, for example, an application mobile, this field would be totally unreal. What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: The counter cache is stable assuming CakePHP is the only thing that accesses your database. If yo've got a mobile application, that should also be accessing your database via a CakePHP API, not directly. And if you do that, counter cache should still be fine.

Comment: Yes, It would be appropiated to access from mobile application to database via CakePHP API, but application do this via PHP Scripts, and they're already too large. In addition mobile app. isn't my matter. I have an idea, I can do "find" of "Model 3" getting the FKs from "Model 1" present on it, and then do paginate passing them as parameter in "conditions". I think its ok, but maybe too increase time of execution (when table grow considerably)??

Comment: See my updated answer. You should use virtual fields - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Comment: So cool! I thought about virtual fields but I didnt believe that they were so powerful, I thought only could be used to concat fields an so. Exactly, i have put virtualfields with the query in my "1st model", and then in the controller i put the condition on the pagination, that this virtual field could be greater than 0! I think everything is OK! Thank you very much buddy!!

Comment: virtual fields are really versatile. You can have quite complex queries in them. Glad to help.